# Dynamic data source for fetching AMI using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

So the following data source will fetch the latest AMI with `component:web` tagged. Let's say I have a handful of components with their own AMI. Instead of creating this same block 5 times, is there a way to make this more dynamic where I can pass in the value of `component`? I can't seem to think of a unique value I can pass in. Do I need to refactor my code a bit?

```
data "aws_ami" "web" {
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:component"
    values = ["web"]
  }

  most_recent = true
}
```

I have a `defaults` module that acts as a metadata lookup where it fetches and outputs basic things like AMI ID and VPC IDs.

## Default Module

```
# defaults/main.tf

data "aws_ami" "web" {
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:component"
    values = ["web"]
  }

  most_recent = true
}

output "web_ami" {
  value = "${data.aws_ami.web.id}"
}
```

## Main code

```
# service_name/main.tf

module "defaults" {
  source      = "../defaults"
  region      = "${var.region}"
  environment = "${var.environment}"
}

module "ftpserver" {
  source .    = "../ec2_instance"
  ami_id      = "${module.defaults.web_ami}"
  ...
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing it that way instead of having the `ec2_instance` module look up the AMI id based on the component and then pass `component` in as a variable to the module?

Comment: What if I need to override the ami id for some reason?

Comment: Add an optional `override_ami_id` variable to the module and then have the instance resource use that if it's populated.

Comment: New terraform guy here ... Got any examples? Im not sure how I would use that new variable as oppose to the latest version the datasource.

Comment: Answered with an example. The main idea is that modules should try to hide some of the complexity away and present a simple interface where possible. The caller of a module should not need to know about how to fetch the "right" AMI most of the time and instead should be able to say that it wants a "web" AMI and let the module handle that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd move the `aws_ami` data source into the module and have it look up the AMI directly rather than have it passed in from outside.

So I would change the `ec2_instance` module to look like:

```
variable "ami_component" {}

data "aws_ami" "selected" {
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:component"
    values = ["${var.ami_component"]
  }

  most_recent = true
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami           = "${data.aws_ami.selected.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

If you then felt like you needed to be able to override the AMI in the `ec2_instance` module you could change that to instead be:

```
variable "ami_component" {}

variable "override_ami" {
  default = ""
}

data "aws_ami" "selected" {
  filter {
    name   = "state"
    values = ["available"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "tag:component"
    values = ["${var.ami_component"]
  }

  most_recent = true
}

resource "aws_instance" "instance" {
  ami           = "${var.override_ami != "" ? var.override_ami : data.aws_ami.selected.id}"
  instance_type = "t2.micro"

  tags {
    Name = "HelloWorld"
  }
}
```

This uses a conditional to check if the `override_ami` variable has been set to something else in which case it will use that, otherwise it will use the `ami_component` variable to look up the appropriate AMI and use that instead.

This has the benefit of moving the AMI selection logic into the Terraform module making the interface to that module much simpler.

Comment: Ahhh ok makes perfect sense. Let me give it a try later today.

Comment: `values = ["${var.ami_component"]` is missing a terminating curly brace after `component` just in case anyone copy/pastes